# Exchange messages between two TUN/TAP running devices

Tags: c, networking, vpn, tun-tap

(I'm new to network programming)I want to use [n2n](https://github.com/ntop/n2n) to create a network of various machines connected to the internet an I want them to exchange data using some protocol like TCP/UDP.
I have started an [issue on their github](https://github.com/ntop/n2n/issues/156) but it seems they have stopped replying.
Please I need help

I have already tried executing their inbuilt function "quick_edge_init" as mentioned in the issue on both the machines and then tried exchanging messages using standard udp taking one as client and other as server.

Quick_edge_init parameters on both the nodes

Node 1

```
  char *device_name    = (char*)"n2n0";
  char *network_name   = (char*)"network";
  char *secret_key     = (char*)"secretkey";
  char *my_mac_address = (char*)"DE:AD:BE:EF:01:10";
  char *my_ipv4_addr   = (char*)"192.168.100.1";
  char *supernode      = (char*)"supernode.ntop.org:7777";
  int  keep_on_running = 1;
```

Node 2

```
  char *device_name    = (char*)"n2n0";
  char *network_name   = (char*)"network";
  char *secret_key     = (char*)"secretkey";
  char *my_mac_address = (char*)"DE:AD:BE:EF:01:10";
  char *my_ipv4_addr   = (char*)"192.168.100.2";
  char *supernode      = (char*)"supernode.ntop.org:7777";
  int  keep_on_running = 1;
```

I just want nodes on this network initiated by my program to exchange messages